# USB MIDI keyboard Akai LPK, jackd

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I got Akai LPK25 and I am trying to make it working on my Ubuntu. I tried to follow a tutorial http://terokarvinen.com/2014/usb-midi-keyboard-on-linux-akai-lpk25-professional, but when I run

```
zynjacku &
```

I get errors

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Failed to connect to JACK.
Failed to initialize zynjacku engine`
```

I figured I may need to run the jackd server first so I installed it and ran

```
jackd -sRp 70 -d alsa -d hw:1 -r 44100 -H -z s
```

but I still can't make zynjacku running and get

```
flex scanner jammed
```

If I run zynaddsubfx and aconnectgui I manage to get signal from the keyboard (the indicator at the bottom gets blue) but I can't hear anythnig.

I tried to manually send some signal to jackd by `ecasound` and it reaches the jackd server but again I can't hear any sound.

I have totally no experience with jackd so that's why my trials are that random. Thanks in advance for your help.

If I run `jackd -sRp 70 -d alsa -d hw:1 -r 44100 -H -z s`, I get

```
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|hwmon|swmeter|-|32bit
Failed to open server
```

Comment: Why are you using `hw:1`?

Comment: This is the one which seemed to work, otherwise (with `hw:0`) jackd didn't start.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Please find the output in the edited question

Comment: There is no error message. Try asking on the jack mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CL suggested, I asked on jack-devel mailing ( http://jack-audio.10948.n7.nabble.com/Jack-Devel-USB-MIDI-keyboard-Akai-LPK-jackd-td18276.html ). The problem is that the zynjack is outdated. Morever, for connecting `aconnectgui` is not necessary.

Let me cite Jeremy from the mailing list:

> This is what I would do to get things going:
>
> - Connect your LPK25 Install necessary software: apt-get install jackd    qjackctl zynaddsubfx
> - Start QjackCtl and set it up for your soundcard, some googling should get you started
> - Start ZynAddSubFX and make the connections in the Audio tab from the Zyn output ports to your playback ports.
> - Do the same for MIDI, connect your LPK25 output to the Zyn input in the ALSA tab of the QjackCTL Connections window.